# Javascript Function not defined error in code

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to Javascript and I don't understand why I am getting an error for this piece of code. Please help me understand what syntax I am got wrong.

```js
var isEven = function(number){
    if(number % 2 = 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};

isEven(5);
```

Comment: What browser did you run this in? In Chrome at least it gives a fairly obvious error message in the console: `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: @RGraham It's a tutorial in codecademy - I am not familiar with how to respond to the error messages yet - But now I'll know what that means in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if(number % 2 = 0)
```

to

```
if(number % 2 === 0)
```

because you want to test if the modulo 2 of number has no remainder. What you wrote was an illegal assignment operation.

Comment: Thanks! I keep forgetting this coming from a VBA background. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
(number % 2 = 0)
```

should be

```
(number % 2 == 0)
```

or

```
(number % 2 === 0)
```

One equal sign is assignment, the double equal sign is "equal to."

More info:

Triple equal sign matches type and value. (This is a good habit to get into using when possible.) Types are like "number", "object", "string" etc.

```
(number % 2 == 0) // true
(number % 2 == "0") // true
(number % 2 === 0) // true
(number % 2 === "0") // false
```

Otherwise, == might work with other things the computer considers zero, maybe null, maybe empty quotes, or maybe not, there's so many caveats in JS typing, === prevents most of those type headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator instead of the equality operator in your if statement.  This causes a JavaScript error because the value on the lefthand side of the operator isn't a variable, it's an expression.

What you want to do is check for equality. To do this, change `=` to `===` in your if statement.

```
if (number % 2 === 0)
```